# Is_Page doesnt detect my page

Tags: functions, theme-development, actions, get-template-part

I want to call Servicedeneme.php which is in main folder of theme, in mysite.com/faq/

It's title is FAQ so I write code for two form which are faq and FAQ.However, it doesnt work.

I write below code to function.php

```
  if (is_page( 'faq' ) or is_page( 'FAQ' )) {
        get_template_part( 'Servicedeneme' );
    }
```

Also when I write below code, wp will error:

```
function show_archieve_styles(){
    if (is_page( 'faq' ) or is_page( 'FAQ' )) {
        get_template_part( 'Servicedeneme' );
    }
}
add_action('wp', 'show_archieve_style');
```

It says there is no function in error.

So, whats the problem?

Comment: If you want to apply a custom template to a specific page name, just name the file `page-faq.php`.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I tried page-faq.php and page-FAQ.php after your comment, but they dont work, why?

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to replace the template file for the entire page or include a certain feature? As @JacobPeattie  mentioned in the comments you may want to check out [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) for replacing the whole template.

The [get_template_part()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) function can be used to include a template part into another file. I think that's your use case here. The problem appears to be where you are trying to add the template. I think you'll want to add the following to `page.php` as that is the default template for pages. I find that the [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) plugin has a useful feature of displaying which template is being used.

```
 // add to page.php where you want your forms.
 if ( is_page( 'faq' ) || is_page( 'FAQ' ) ) {
        get_template_part( 'Servicedeneme' );
    }
```